# Perfomance difference between DATE and TINYINT

Tags: sql-server, performance

2 similar queries result in radically different execution times.

I have 2 similar tables. The only difference between them is one contains a DATE datatype and the other as a TINYINT. 
Here is what the tables look like. They are temp tables and the primary key is the only index.

```
CREATE TABLE #Carrier_DOB(
    Carrier_Record_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    DOB_DT DATE NOT NULL,
    Cohort_Person_ID INT NULL
)
CREATE INDEX IX_Carrier_DOB ON #Carrier_DOB(Cohort_Person_ID)

CREATE TABLE #Carrier_Race(
    Carrier_Record_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    BENE_RACE_CD TINYINT NOT NULL,
    Cohort_Person_ID INT NULL
)
CREATE INDEX IX_Carrier_Race ON #Carrier_Race(Cohort_Person_ID)
```

Here are the contents via sp_spaceused:

```
name            rows                    reserved    data        index_size  unused
#Carrier_DOB    75836908                2038528 KB  2029088 KB  7456 KB 1984 KB
#Carrier_Race   72139975                1647744 KB  1639552 KB  6016 KB 2176 KB
```

Here are the queries I am curious about:

```
--Query1
SELECT *
INTO #DOB_Differences
FROM   #Carrier_DOB
WHERE  Cohort_Person_ID IN ( 
    SELECT a.Cohort_Person_ID FROM #Carrier_DOB a
    INNER JOIN #Carrier_DOB b 
       ON b.Cohort_Person_ID = a.Cohort_Person_ID 
       AND b.DOB_DT <> a.DOB_DT
    GROUP BY a.Cohort_Person_ID ) --466464 rows in 19:30

--Query2
SELECT #
INTO #Race_Differences
FROM #Carrier_Race
WHERE  Cohort_Person_ID IN ( 
    SELECT a.Cohort_Person_ID FROM #Carrier_Race a
    INNER JOIN #Carrier_Race b 
      ON b.Cohort_Person_ID = a.Cohort_Person_ID 
      AND b.BENE_RACE_CD <> a.BENE_RACE_CD
    GROUP BY a.Cohort_Person_ID ) -- 3476884 rows in  0:13
```

The main difference between these 2 queries is that one is comparing a DATE field and the other a CHAR(1). I am very surprised that Query1 takes 19 minutes and Query2 only takes 13 seconds. Is this normal? I don't typically deal with 75 Million row tables so I have never noticed this before.
I have not added more indexes because this is just one step in my process.
Here are the [query plans](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryf9-1MXS). They are quite different but I don't understand why.
Here are the actual [query plans](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SklVjJGmB) plus I added indexes as shown above.
The indexes dropped the time down to 12:24 minutes for both queries, but I still don't understand why Query1 is so much slower than Query1.

Comment: Is there an index on `DOB_DT`? If so, please **[edit]** the question and show how it is defined. If they really are temp tables as shown here, put indexes on the temp tables as well. Also, please always use https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ for questions about query performance.

Comment: What do the execution plans look like? IO statistics? Without any indexes on Cohort_Person_ID  the server has to scan the entire table again for each row, resulting in N^3 comparisions - that `WHERE .. IN` will result in yet another full scan. I suspect it's the distribution of Carrier_ID/Cohort_IDs that causes the difference, not the date or byte comparison.

Comment: I am not convinced the difference is down to data types - Query 1 returns 466K rows (which suggests the "in clause" is doing a lot of work), whereas query 2 returns 3.5M rows (nearly 8 times more), which suggests the "in clause" is having an easier time. 
I'd post an EXPLAIN of both the IN clause statements.

Comment: i would suggest rewriting this into using a `INNER JOIN` instead of `IN()` ..

Comment: Can you post actual execution plans instead of the estimated ones?

Comment: Sean Lange, actual execution plans have been posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the plans it looks like what is happening is the tinyint is acting like it can do a hash join where the date can't.  This makes sense to me since a tinyint is so small it is basically the size of a hash and can be used as a native hash.  This is what I think is happening.

Simple to solve if I am right, just make a non-unique index on the date field in the first table. Should be a lot faster.

---

Just pointing out if the goal is to find items with more than one of these values you can use group by and having -- like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM #Carrier_DOB
GROUP BY Cohort_Person_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DOB_DT) > 1
```

Comment: You are correct Hogan.  I simplified the queries for the post. I am really pulling all the fields into yet another temp table. I will edit the queries to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks Hogan. That is interesting how the different types are compared differently. I just added an index on DOB_DT and it's still chugging awat at 8 minutes so while the index should help, it still cannot overcome the the difference in counts of the 2 queries I have posted in the answer.

Comment: did the plan change to use hash with the index?  13 billion is a lot more than 3 million but it should not have to do 13 billion reads if it has the index -- maybe you did not run statistics on the index before you ran the query?

Comment: It did not. Here is the plan:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1mHkWzmB
However, I didn't run statistics on the index first.
I also added
```
b.Carrier_Record_ID<>a.Carrier_Record_ID
``` 
to try and reduce the number of rows in the inner join.